# Not able to find out specific span class while webscraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I need to scrap https://www.nerdwallet.com/rates/banking/cd-accounts to get APY informarion for all the banks listed on this page. I need to find out this span class **_1f39sH _24b0kK DFVVwC** to extract those rates.[CD Rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUjDP.jpg)

I am using this code but getting blank list

```
import requests
import html5lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.nerdwallet.com/rates/banking/cd-accounts'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')
span = soup.find_all('span', class_ = "_1f39sH _24b0kK DFVVwC")
print(span)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external URL so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. You can use `requests` to load this data:

```py
import json

import requests

api_url = "https://www.nerdwallet.com/api/marketplace/offers/v1/banking/search"

payload = {
    "fields": [
        "offer.derived_details.apply_link",
        "offer.derived_details.display_apy",
        "offer.derived_details.should_throttle_monetization",
        "offer.details.account_details",
        "offer.details.apy_annotation",
        "offer.details.apy",
        "offer.details.balance_to_avoid_fees",
        "offer.details.benefits",
        "offer.details.bonus_amount",
        "offer.details.bonus_details",
        "offer.details.cd_deposit_term",
        "offer.details.direct_deposit_waive",
        "offer.details.display_pages",
        "offer.details.display_status",
        "offer.details.fee_atm",
        "offer.details.fee_debit_replacement",
        "offer.details.fee_early_closure",
        "offer.details.fee_monthly",
        "offer.details.fee_overdraft",
        "offer.details.fee_paper_statements",
        "offer.details.fee_stop_payment",
        "offer.details.minimum_balance",
        "offer.details.offer_url",
        "offer.details.outbound_cta_percentage",
        "offer.details.states",
        "offer.product.details.display_name",
        "offer.product.details.display_slug",
        "offer.product.details.display_status",
        "offer.product.details.product_audience",
        "offer.product.details.rating_stars",
        "offer.product.details.sub_product_type",
        "offer.product.institution.details.branch_count",
        "offer.product.institution.details.display_name",
        "offer.product.institution.details.display_slug",
        "offer.product.institution.details.display_status",
        "offer.product.institution.details.federally_insured",
        "offer.product.institution.details.logo_url",
        "offer.product.institution.details.nw_rating_bank_experience",
        "offer.product.institution.details.nw_rating_overdraft_fee",
        "offer.product.institution.details.nw_rating",
        "offer.product.institution.details.nw_review_url",
        "offer.product.institution.details.type",
        "offer.product.institution.id",
        "offer.product.id",
        "offer.id",
        "offer.product.institution.status",
        "offer.product.status",
        "offer.status",
        "offer.entity_type",
        "offer.product_type",
    ],
    "pagination": {"limit": 10, "offset": 0},
    "query": [
        {"field": "offer.details.display_status", "type": "eq", "value": "ACTIVE"},
        {
            "field": "offer.product.details.display_status",
            "type": "eq",
            "value": "ACTIVE",
        },
        {
            "field": "offer.product.institution.details.display_status",
            "type": "eq",
            "value": "ACTIVE",
        },
        {"field": "offer.details.display_pages", "type": "in", "value": ["TOOLS"]},
        {
            "field": "offer.product.details.product_audience",
            "type": "neq",
            "value": "business",
        },
        {
            "field": "offer.product.details.sub_product_type",
            "type": "in",
            "value": ["CD"],
        },
        {
            "field": "offer.product.institution.details.type",
            "type": "in",
            "value": ["BK", "IB", "CU", "NBFSP"],
        },
        {"field": "offer.product.details.rating_stars", "type": "geq", "value": 3},
        {"field": "offer.details.minimum_balance", "type": "leq", "value": 5000},
        {
            "type": "or",
            "value": [
                {
                    "field": "offer.details.states",
                    "type": "contains_one_of",
                    "value": ["CA"],
                },
                {"field": "offer.details.states", "type": "exists", "value": False},
            ],
        },
        {"field": "offer.details.cd_deposit_term", "type": "leq", "value": 720},
    ],
    "sort": [
        {"field": "offer.details.apy", "order": "desc"},
        {"field": "offer.details.cd_deposit_term", "order": "asc"},
        {"field": "offer.details.minimum_balance", "order": "asc"},
    ],
}

headers = {
    "X-Caller-Client-ID": "offer-shopping-experience",
}

data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload, headers=headers).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for o in data["data"]["offers"]:
    name = o["product"]["institution"]["details"]["display_name"]["value"]
    apy = o["details"]["apy"]["value"]

    print(f"{name:<30} {apy:<10}")
```

Prints:

```
LendingClub Bank               5.65      
Bread Savings                  5.6       
BMO Alto                       5.5       
Bread Savings                  5.15      
Discover Bank                  5         
Discover Bank                  5         
Discover Bank                  4.3       
Discover Bank                  3.5       
Discover Bank                  3.4       
Discover Bank                  2
```